TV show about science hosted by two men
It's a show in which two men just have fun and explain about different types of science stuff. I think it was aired on Nat Geo, though I could be wrong. The time period of this show could be close to 2010.
At the end of every episode one of the men cuts something in half to explain how it works while showing its insides. One time he tried to cut a engine but couldn't. In another episode, they showed how to beat a lie detector.
Its intro or outro contained a scene in which their lab coats were cut off from their body.

Sounds like "What's Inside"; https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSrPuHtKbst7Zy8pyWn_3Cg

I have found the name, It's - I didn't know that.

@AdityaKumar You should be able to post that as an answer, along with a description of how it matches. You'll then be able to accept it to mark your question as resolved.

The name of the show is I Didn't Know That.

From airbags to teabags, toothpaste to tea, and condoms to crash helmets, each episode is a mind-blowing cavalcade of crazy demonstrations and rarely-heard info about everyday stuff.





you should mark your answer as accepted
